# How to display build version in React/webpack app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, version

I need to version every build and display it in app. I've tried to use this tutorial but it didn't work for me
https://dmitriy-comarov.medium.com/app-version-from-package-json-with-react-and-webpack-84097bd3f4f9

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: If you don't provide what exactly you have done, how can we help you to troubeshoot? The way is addressed in the article seems to work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still can follow this tutorial above but if you are not using typescript you don't have to declare 'VERSION' variable. You can call it straight from webpack. And don't forget add 'version' property in your package.json